# Python write-biased readers-writer lock

Tags: python, locking

Is anyone aware of a tried-and-tested python implementation of a [write-biased Readers-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)? A Google search yielded an [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577803-reader-writer-lock-with-priority-for-writers/) but am unsure if this is battle-tested. Should I be looking at something else before investing time in incorporating and testing this recipe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class SHLock of the module [threading2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/threading2).

The method acquire of this class has, in addition to the usual parameters, the boolean optional parameter `shared`, default to `False`.

As the parameter's name says, if `shared` is `True` you are asking to acquire a shared lock, instead if `shared` is `False` you are asking to acquire an exclusive lock.

In the readers/writers problem, the readers should acquire a shared lock, while the writers should acquire a not shared (exclusive) lock.

It implements the lock assuring no starvation for both readers and writers.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to this solution. Can the SHLock be configured to be writer-biased?

Comment: +1 for the pointer to threading2, but i really am looking for a writer-biased lock implementation